# R is regular local rings of Krull dimension 2.Can we find any ideal of height 2 different from m?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Maybe it is too easy but I want to know that: If $R$ is regular local ring of Krull dimension $2$ and $m$ is the maximal ideal of $R$. (It means that height $m$ is $2$). Can we find  any ideal of height $2$ different from $m$?

Comment: Rolled back a pointless edit of an off-topic question

Answer (score 2):

No.  Since it is the unique maximal ideal, $\mathfrak m$ contains every prime ideal (its complement is the set of all units of $R$).